# CRUD-in-one design

Tags: usability, gui-design

So I have a requirement to design a "Create, Update, Delete" interface all-in-one (without a table). Here's the basic functionality, or flow, as I understand it:

You enter an ID into an input box and push "search" or "go" or whatever... if the ID doesn't exist, you take the user to a "wizard" that allows them to add that ID to the "database." If the ID does exist, a pop-up will open saying "Do you want to delete or edit this record?"... delete will delete the record and edit will take the user to the same "wizard" for adding a record, just that all input fields in the wizard will be pre-populated.

Speaking from a generic-user point-of-view, I know that this whole "Create/Update/Delete" is confusing. That's why I'm wondering if there's any way possible to keep the same flow (one place to do all CUD operations), but still maintain GOOD user experience. If anyone has done something like this, I'd love to know how you actually designed it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following suggestion :

- The user etners the ID (screen 1)
- If the ID does not exist, the ID field is disbled, the status is set to NEW and the user can enter the details of the new entry (screen 2)
- If the ID exists, the ID field is disbled, the status is set to UPDATE and the user can make any changes needed or delete the record (screen 3)
- When the user is done with one ID and wants to enter another one, he clicks on clear which clears all fields and enables the ID field.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb6Hy4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This definitely gives me a good starting point, thank you!